# What is a Nature Word™?

Tags: pattern, no-computers, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Nature Word™.
Here is a list of Nature™ and not-Nature™ words:

| Nature Words™ | Not Nature Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PANTS | SHIRTS |
| BEAR | STAND |
| HUMANE | NICE |
| BATTY | CRAZY |
| PLANT | TREE |
| SHARE | GIVE |
| FOXY | CLEVER |
| REEL | PULL |
| EMULATE | IMITATE |
| PRAT | IDIOT |

What is the rule to tell whether a word is a Nature Word™ or not? Why is it called a Nature Word™?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Nature Words™ contain the name of an animal – pANTs, BEAR, HUMANe, BATty, plANT, sHARE, FOXy, rEEL, EMUlate, pRAT.